# Meaning of "gives way"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> It is at this point that I am woken by my own screaming. I switch on the light and try to control the desperate gasping for air which always seizes me after the dream. Around me stands the familiar furniture of our bedroom, and, over the bed itself, the family portraits, ikons in their high starched collars and braided coats, Hungarian Baroque and Beidermeier, my all-seeing, all-knowing ancestors. They alone are witness to the number of times I have raced down during the night to open the door to the rescuers and the ambulance; and they alone know how often I have stood there **while the silence of the early-morning streets slowly gives way to the sounds of restlessly tossing trees and the cries of prowling cats that flood in through the open door**, imagining what would happen if my struggle with the key proved in vain, and the lock failed to turn.

Dose "gives way to" mean: replaces with?

and the whole sentence in bold mean: while little by little the silence of the early morning repleces with sounds of tossing trees and the cries of cats?

Source:The Door
By
Magda Szabó
 
Translated Len Rix

Comment: Yes, that's the idea - in the sense of **gradually replaced by**

Comment: Viser - You have it the wrong way round. The sounds replace the silence (or, as Ronald says, the silence _is replaced by_ the sounds).

Comment: Yes I meant that, maybe I wrote it wrong‌. I meant that the silence gradually disappered and the air filled with the sounds of trees and cats. Am I right?